# When to use TCP hole punching technique and why to use it?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, nat, hole-punching

I am studying the **TCP hole punching** technique and have got some knowledge from this article: [TCP_hole_punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching). But I don't understand below part:

```
      Network Drawing
      Peer A ←→ Gateway A ← .. Network .. → Gateway B ←→ Peer B  

      Types of NAT
      The availability of the TCP-hole-punching technique depends 
      on the type ofcomputer port allocation used by the NAT. When 
      two peers, A and B, instantiate TCP   connections by binding 
      to local ports Pa and Pb, respectively, **they need to know 
      the remote  endpoint NAT port in order to make the connection**.
```

Here are some questions, could somebody help explain? Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!!

Q1. Suppose we have a client app running behind NAT1 and a server app 
    running behind NAT2. They will have messaging and file transfer communication. 
    The pattern will be the server listens and accepts connection
    from the client. **Do they need to use the TCP hole punching to keep the tcp
    connection work?**

Q2. **Is the TCP hole punching technique necessary only when it's peer to peer 
    communication and both parties are connecting to each other (e.g., 2x CONNECT(), no LISTEN(), ACCEPT(), etc.)?**

Q3. In the above text, what does it mean of "they need to know the remote  endpoint NAT port in order to make the connection"? **Why do they need to know the remote endpoint NAT port?Don't they only need to know the local port of the other machine?**

For example, suppose the pair are (ClientA, publicIPA, LocalPortA), (ClientB, publicIPB, LocalPortB). If the ClientA wants to communicate with ClientB via TCP, it may do something like this:

```
         clientBAddr.port = LocalPortB;
         clientBAddr.ip = inet_addr(publicIPB);
         connect(fdA, clientBAddr,...);
```

why would it need to know information such as NATPortA and NATPortB? Is there any problem if the clientA and clientB don't care about the NATA and NATB?

Comment: For Q3, ClientA needs to know NATPortB because that's the port it has to `connect()` to.

Comment: @Celada , but for ClientA, the application will do it like this: { serveraddr.port = LocalPortB, serveraddr.ip = inet_addr(publicIPB), connect(serveraddr); } so why would it need NATPortB?

Comment: Connecting to `LocalPortB` won't work unless `LocalPortB` *happens* to be equal to `NATPortB`. If they are not equal, then this incoming TCP SYN packet will be dropped by the B side NAT box because it doesn't match any TCP connection that is tracked by that router.

Comment: Not sure what is off-topic in this question.It might not have some code in the OP, and it could have asked 1 specific question rather than 3, but i believe since related to network programming, it should have been allowed to remain open. I don't think this would be apt at serverfault or superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Since this post is reopened and nobody leaves an answer until this moment, I would like to answer it myself based on this article: [Peer-to-Peer Communication Across Network Address Translators](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html)

About Q1, yes. Without mechanism like hole-punching, the packets one side use to sync with the other side will be dropped by the routers.

About Q2, no exactly. Listening sockets won't work directly. You need other tricks.